# Get result of a build step in Hudson/Jenkins to re-use it in another one

Tags: ant, hudson, jenkins

My question may be silly but I've been trying several ways and I still can't do what I want, i.e.:

- use the scp target of Ant to target a remote machine and execute
  a script there
- this script creates a dynamic list of files
- get this list of files (only their names) back in Hudson to use it in the next build step (another scp from Ant)

I tried to use environment variables but they are interpreted by Hudson so I'm stuck here...

Globally my question would be: how to get a result from an Ant build step ?

Thanks for your ideas,

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

You may find [File parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) useful. This allows you to create an input file, pass it to build. You may need to write script/ant script to process the file though.

In the long term you may evaluate a Hudson farm. This will allow to create tasks that span multiple machines , pass results around. (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID(s) of the job that triggered your job via the API and fetch their status.

Comment: Ok to get the job status, but how could it help me get the result of a script run on a remote machine via SSH ?